# Find the derivative of y^2=x as a function of y.

Tags: calculus

Find the derivative of $$y^2=x$$ as a function of y.

i have found for the function of x, it will be $$\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$$

however for the function of y will be $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2y$$ ?
  it looks too simple, and I'm sure it's wrong.

Comment: $$y^2 = x \implies (y^2)' = 2yy' = (x)' =1 \implies y' = \frac{1}{2y}$$

See [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation).

Comment: Do you mean $\dfrac {dx} {dy}=2y$?

Comment: yes, seems like a mistake in a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ y^2 = x , 2 \, y \, y^{'} = 1, $$

$$ y' = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2y}. $$

Answer (score -2):

As a function fo $y$, you should have $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2y}$ which is the same as $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. Note however that square is a function only if we choose the positive square root.   So there is no need for the plus/or minus.